# Android Eclipse can't find ImageView import what do I do?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, imageview

Hi this is my line of code:

```
 ImageView imgEncrypt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.encryptImg);
```

and the red line pops up under ImageView, which with other things like Button I'd click to import it. However, it's not coming up for ImageView.

jI've even typed in manually what to import, and yet that still doesn't work, it just asks me to create that class.

Thanks

Comment: Try closing your project and re-starting `Eclipse`

Comment: @LancePreston It didn't work ://

Comment: Can you zip your android project and drop it here : http://www.nippyzip.com/ ?

Comment: @LancePreston I uploaded it, is that all I needed to do

Comment: Share the link to access it

Comment: @ManvirSpeedySinghDhinse Please avoid eclipse . Use Android Studio

Comment: @LancePreston http://www.nippyzip.com/uploads/150125012255-91793.zip

Comment: @LancePreston It's a in a class named something like EncryptImage

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried cleaning your project ? From menu bar Project > Clean